# How to open a PDF within a Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to open a PDF within a Cocoa application. I tried the following to open the PDF using Preview.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"filepath"]];
```

But I would like to open the PDF attached to a window, similar to Xcode's Help window. How do you achieve this using PDFKit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PDFView for opening PDF files within your application.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH203-SW1

Answer (score 5):

I imported QuartzFrameWork, and added a `PDFView` in the xib. The following code did the job for me:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"filePath"]
PDFDocument *pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:url];
[_pdfView setDocument:pdfDoc];
```

Answer (score 0):

in .h file

```
@interface MyViewController:UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize documentInteractionController;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
documentInteractionController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
}
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
return self;
}
-(void) openPdf{
NSString *filePath=filePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
if (URL) {
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
    [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
    [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
}
```